# I don't understand why my question was closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

[What current would be measured in the following circuit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/635476/179151)

There was some commentary about it being a homework question, which it isn't, I genuinely want to understand what happens when the point of intersection moves faster than the speed of light. I actually find this an interesting question.

Comment: I don't see any comments saying it is a homework question. Note that the closure reason says homework-LIKE.

Comment: Someone added a tag saying homework but i removed it

Comment: The question reads like an exercise you would find in a textbook.

Comment: So the issue is the way it reads? I am clearly looking for understanding on how electromagnetic fields affect current in conductors.

Comment: Also, what if the question is modified to add that the rods then come to stop, what reading would appear on the ammeter over time?

Comment: How is this not an assignment question?  It is certainly nearly identical to typical textbook questions...

Answer (score 6):

Your post looks like an exercise that was pulled from a text book. I would say this is because it involves a hypothetical, ideal situation and it concludes with "what is the answer and why?", which is a typical way text books end some exercises.

> I am clearly looking for understanding on how electromagnetic fields affect current in conductors.

If you want the question to be reopened, I suggest asking specifically about the physics concepts you do not understand that are preventing your from answering this question yourself. As of now, I do not see how your post explicitly asks about how electromagnetic fields affect currents. It just seems to ask how to solve this exercise.

> what if the question is modified to add that the rods then come to stop, what reading would appear on the ammeter over time?

The post would probably remain closed. Adding another question will not change the content that was there previously when the question was closed. Edit the question to explicitly focus on the concepts you are confused about.